# C# ASP.Net WebForm Membership Extra User Details (Profile)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm learning how to use the ASP.net membership, when a user registers they just create a username and password, however i want to create a page on my website called "profile" where they can fill in extra details such as firstname, lastname, date of birth ect. However i don't see where i can place this in the asp.net membership database. Theres an asp.net_profile table however i'm not sure how this works.

Could someone please explain how i can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should treat the built-in membership stuff as a black box -- extending the stock membership schema is a pretty bad idea in general.

The profiles is pretty ugly to be honest -- kind if handy for storing miscellaneous settings but I would hate to store data I cared about extracting at some point. The main issue is it stores stuff in an an opaque serialized field so it is hard to extract your data. Overhead can be nasty as it will deserialize this stuff on every request, so if you have an extensive profile it can get expensive. And it isn't worth pulling out someone's extra profile info every request in most cases.

As for usage, I'd start with the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Also note that there are additional challenges in MVC -- it is not wired into that stack as directly, though one can still make use of it.

All that said, you probably want to build out your own member profile table of some sort here. You probably will double-book some data with the built-in membership bits but that is OK. You will want to setup this table with some sort of relationship to the membership -- I prefer using an "owner account id" structure rather than keying it directly to accounts as that makes things much more flexible. For example, it lets users have multiple profiles if that becomes necessary.

Comment: Yes ill being using WebForm, on one hand your telling me its a bad idea creating a new table in the schema to hold profile data and on the other hand your saying storing information like profile details which im going to need to extract is not a good idea to store in the aspnet_profile table due to serialization. What would you suggest out of the two? Creating a new table?

Comment: No, I said *extending the membership schema* was a bad idea. I extended the answer a bit to clairify things.

Comment: We have used the approach @WyattBarnett proposed successfully in our application. We use a table with `UserId` which is the `UserName` in the `dbo.aspnet_Users` table, then added all our extra stuff (Like Address, Salutation, etc..)

Answer (score 4):

You will probably have to create MembershipUser first by using Membership.CreateUser, grab the newly created user's id and then insert his extra profile information in seperate table (like ExtendedUserInfo etc) and link that with aspnet_Users table with forein key.

Comment: Ye this is the easiest way to do it, however i want to learn how i can do it using the aspnet_profile table :) Also i'm unsure how i can ensure that the profile page they are viewing is the details of the person who is currently loged in.

Comment: @user1638362 aspnet_Profile table is not at all recommended, it's poorly designed, although won't matter for small scale applications but will matter greatly for medium/large scale applications.

Comment: But whether solution that you suggested is scallable? What if tommorow MS will release some membership update, and everything I've linked would be already published, I would get so much pain in ..., won't I?

Answer (score 2):

So as you have already configured the membership and roles section, you do the same with the profile section. But here you can provide properties like:

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <properties>
     <add name="Name" />
     <add name="Weight" type="System.Int32" />
     <add name="BirthDate" 
          type="System.DateTime" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

In your code you can call Profile.Name and assign a value, the ASP.Membership framework manages storing the values.

More information about how to use it are on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8b58y5d(v=vs.100).aspx it's a bit old but shows the basics.